# How to fix error 'stream_copy_to_stream(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory' in Larvel?

Tags: laravel

I'm getting an error

> stream_copy_to_stream(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a
> directory

when i upload a csv file.
I changed in the configuration of `php.ini` and I increased the values of `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` and `memory_limit` but i still get the error. My code is :

```
public function parseImport(Request $req) {
        if ($req->file()) {
            $fileModel = new File();
            $fileName = time().'_'.$req->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $filePath =  $req->file('file')->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');


            $this->data = ImportHelpers::parseCsv(public_path($filePath));

            $fileModel->name = $fileName;
            $fileModel->file_path = $filePath;
            $fileModel->save();

            return back()
                ->with('success','Le fichier a été bien télécharger.')
                ->with('file', $fileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: It is important to restart the php-fpm service also, if not using php with apache.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was making sure my form had this tag AFTER the file upload input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000"/>
```